# Just solved a problem, not on StackOverflow, but would like to share the solution

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

I just spent a few hours solving a problem, but it wasn't on StackOverflow. StackOverflow seems like a good place to post the result, but since it's already answered, it isn't really a question any more. Is it still ok to post the question and answer on StackOverflow, or is there a better place to do that?

Comment: I can't imagine this would be a problem. Others might really appreciate it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to contains general advice for what to do if you have a question you know the answer to and are considering asking it. Generally, let other users have a shot at giving an answer before you accept your own. Whether you provide your answer from the get-go or wait a few days for that, that's up to you, but it's always good to see if someone else can answer the question first.

Answer (score 4):

You're encouraged to go ahead and ask the question and answer it yourself if it isn't already on Stack Overflow somewhere.  Do a search first, but ask and answer away if you don't find it.

Note that you'll even get the [Self-Learner Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) if your answer is upvoted 3 or more times.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's okay to post it here.

It's the "blog" part of Stack Overflow (see [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about))

[image: blog part]

Answer (score 0):

You can always post the question and if you don't get the response/answer from someone else right away, you can then post the solution yourself as an answer.

Just make the question/problem statement real...